# Grails deploy on Tomcat6

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails, deployment

while trying to deploy a Grails application into tomcat6 I ran into some problems: I used the `grails war` command to build up a war, then copied it to `var/lib/tomcat6/webapps` and tried to restart the container.

I had to change default Tomcat policy to skip security exceptions, since I couldn't access environment variable (like `grails.env`), then tried again but it gives me an exception related to instantiating something, but it's not clear where should I try to fix the error, according to tomcat6 logs the problem is:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsC$
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext$
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [Hiberna$
>           ... 1 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment

It seems like it's unable to load `org.hibernate.cfg.Environment` class.

I checked the `applicationContext.xml` and it refers to `grails.xml` to search for plugins, in this last file I actually have `HibernateGrailsPlugin`.

Where should I look to find if the plugin is present?

Comment: First thing to try is to switch off the security manager in tomcat.

Comment: As I wrote I already switched it off! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a grails guy, but you seem to be missing the hibernate-core dependencies.  You could try to drop [that .jar](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar) into your server shared lib and see if that resolves your problem.  Ideally this would be located somewhere in your grails war libs but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 4):

I have not had your specific problem, I would suggest you try running

```
grails clean
```

Then try

```
grails run-war
```

If it's runs successfully then try deploying it.

I have found when you get weird errors from grails it's time to do a clean.

Comment: Running grails clean beforehand did the trick - Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Placing the jar file `hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar` in tomcat/lib did the trick. 
Thanks Buddy!

Strange thing is:
I had the older version of the same jar file in the war, but it was giving exception. The application works fine from within *NetBeans* using *Jetty*, but deploying it on tomcat gives this problem.

Anyways, it's working now by placing the jar file `hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar` in tomcat/lib.

Thanks again